# Observing unexpected Output : Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
a = Number(prompt());
b = Number(prompt());
if (a == b) {
  document.write("a==b")
} else if (a > b) {
  document.write("a>b")
} else {
  document.write("a<b")
}
```

using this script Input : a = 10, b = 20 Output : a

I am expecting a<b as a output, Please help, if I am doing any mistake.

Comment: simple fix: don't use `document.write` ... ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having "<" in your result which will be treated as a element opening. So you need to use &lt for "<" and &gt for ">".

```js
a = Number(prompt());
b = Number(prompt());
if (a == b) {
  document.write("a==b")
} else if (a > b) {
  document.write("a&gt;b")
} else {
  document.write("a&lt;b")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<b` is interpreted as the start of a `<b>` tag. Your (malformed HTML) code results in the browser rendering:

```
a
<b <="" body="">
</b>
```

Don't use `document.write` - and if you do have to use it, keep in mind that you're writing HTML markup, not plain text.

Append an element or text node to the document instead.

```js
const append = (text) => document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = text;

a = Number(prompt());
b = Number(prompt());
if (a == b) {
  append("a==b")
} else if (a > b) {
  append("a>b")
} else {
  append("a<b")
}
```